# IE problem: Div positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want my page to look like this:

```
+------+------+
|first |third |
|      |      |
+------+------+
|second|     
|      |      
+------+
```

In the latest version of FF and Chrome the snipped below works as it should. But in IE the output looks like this:

```
+------+
|first | 
|      |    
+------+------+
|second| third|    
|      |      |
+------+------+
```

My snipped

```
 <style>
    #wrapper
    {
        width: 680px;
    }

    #first
    {
        background: Red;
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #second
    {
        background: Green;
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #third
    {
        background: Red;
    }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- 1st two Divs-->
    <div id="first">Div ONE</div>
    <div id="second">Div TWO</div>
    <!-- 3rd Div should be on the top right side next to div one -->
    <div id="third">Div Three</div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate it if you could give me a solution **without altering the html markup**.

Thank you for your Time!

Andrew, Switzerland

Comment: have you tried float:right for the third div?

Comment: yes but it doesn't generate the right output.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 8

Comment: What are the dimensions of the boxes? Are they fixed? Be detailed ...

Comment: as you can see in the snipped above just the width is fixed...

Comment: Wrapper width is 680px but the first and second boxes have a 500px width? Third is what, 180px?

Comment: @Andrew What is your DOCTYPE?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example. Working for me in chrome, ie7 and ie8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this should work:

```
#wrap { width:800px; position:relative; }
#first, #second, #third { width:400px; height:400px; }
#third { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; }
```

**Working demo:** http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/layout.html

Comment: This is a rather inflexible solution. What if the third container has content which requires it to be 1200px heigh?

Comment: Thanks! This solution works for me since the third div will never be heigher than the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style>
    #wrapper
    {
        width: 680px;
    }

    #first
    {
        background: Red;
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #second
    {
        background: Green;
         width: 500px;

    }

    #third
    {
        background: Red;
        float: left;

    }
</style>
```

You'd have to float the third div left, and remove the float from the second div.

You won't have to edit the html, but will have to re-order the divs:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">Div ONE</div>
    <div id="third">Div Three</div>
    <div id="second">Div TWO</div>
</div>
```

That will give you the order of display you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but as I said, the html should be untouched.

Comment: I have another solution which would leave the html untouched, but it depends on the dimensions of the boxes - are they fixed?

Answer (score 0):

many ways to solve. set wrapper width to 1000px. also you've tried `float: left;` on #third?
  ..and possibly a tutorial like this will help you: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Style-Sheets/DIV-Based-Layout-with-CSS/

Comment: ..also check out IE box-model bugs / quirks mode rendering

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<style>
    #wrapper
    {
        width: 680px;
    }

    #first-second-wrapper {
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #first
    {
        background: Red;
    }

    #second
    {
        background: Green;
    }

    #third
    {
        background: Red;
        margin-left: 500px;
    }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- 1st two Divs-->
    <div id="first-second-wrapper">
       <div id="first">Div ONE</div>
       <div id="second">Div TWO</div>
    </div>
    <!-- 3rd Div should be on the top right side next to div one -->
    <div id="third">Div Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but isn't there a solution which leaves the html untouched?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of IE you are testing but this renders correctly in my IE8. When I switch to IE7 standards mode using the dev toolbar I get the problem. This can be solved with this css:

```
#second
    {
        background: Green;
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
        clear:both;
    }
```

You may need to include this in a conditional comment as I am unsure of the effects on other browsers. Here is [an example](http://jsbin.com/ihatu3/2/) of this.